# Depending SQL on entered values

Tags: sql, input

I have seven inputboxes in which people can enter values. These values are compared with a table and eventually a result comes rolling out, it's a search function. Now I had a page with three inputboxes and dit the following:

```
if (box1 is filled && box2 is filled & box 3 is filled) {
sql="take all three values into account when comparing..";
}

if (box1 is not filled && box2 is not filled & box 3 is nog filled) {
sql="take no values into account when comparing..";
}

and so on...
```

For three boxes this is OK, you have  only a few combinations with three boxes. However,
this is not doable for 7 boxes, you get a whole lot more combinations! How do I make
my SQL dependable on the filled in fields? Hope you guys have a clever solution!

Comment: Why can't you do this within the SQL query? If you add a sample of the query, I'll try to help with it.

Comment: Gonna try the solution below first, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the query in pieces. Like:

```
StringBuilder where=new StringBuilder();
String conj=" where ";
if (box1.length()>0)
{
  where.append(conj).append("value1=").append(esc(box1));
  conj=" and ";
}
if (box2.length()>0)
{
  where.append(conj).append("value2=").append(esc(box2));
  conj=" and ";
}
... etc ...
String sql="select value1, value2, value3 from mytable" + where.toString();
```

Couple of notes:

Assuming you have no idea what combination of fields may be entered, you may need to do some playing to get your conjuctions right, i.e. you don't want the query to say "where and value2='x'". The above code puts "where" before the first condition and "and" before each of the following.

Side note: When you build a query like this, you need to watch for SQL injection. Write an escape function -- here I'm assuming you call it "esc" -- that doubles any quote marks. For most SQL engines, that's all you have to worry about. Some have other magic characters, like backslah, that you also need to escape. Alternatively, you can build a prepared statement and then go back and fill in the values. This is safer but forces you to check which fields were filled in twice, once to build the SQL and a second time to fill in the values. This is a little messy but it's safer. Never ever ever take values entered by the user and plug them into a SQL statement by just putting "'"+value+"'": this leaves you wide open to the hacker who enter "' ; delete from user; select * from user where 'x'='". All he has to do is guess one table name right.

Comment: I went with a form of your solution, not the exact thing, but still thanks for thelp!

Comment: Don't concatenate sql-strings but use sql-parameters to avoid sql-injection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) (or `ISNULL`):

```
...
WHERE Column1 = COALESCE(@Column1, Column1) 
AND   Column2 = COALESCE(@Column2, Column2) 
...
AND   Column7 = COALESCE(@Column7, Colum7)
```

So only if the parameter is not null the `WHERE` is applied on that field.

Comment: huh, I didn't know about this

Comment: From what I understand, COALESCE is to check if a field in my table is empty right? I wanna check if the entered value in my inputbox is empty or not.

Comment: @user1555076: 1) you should always use `parameters` to prevent sql-injection 2) `COALESCE` replaces a null value with another value. So if a paremeter is null, it will fallback to the value of the field. Hence  it will never be filtered out because the value is always the value you're seearching(similar to a filter of `1=1`).